# Using p-steps component from PrimeNG in small resolutions

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I am trying to shrink the `p-steps` component from [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/steps/personal) in order to prevent overflow in small screen resolutions. This is my current code:

```html
    <div class="d-flex card mb-4">
       <p-steps [model]="items" [(activeIndex)]="currentWizardCard" [readonly]="false"></p-steps>
    </div>
```

This looks fine in a large screen: [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndBeV.png)

But when reducing the screen resolution the steps overflow: [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1LCY.png)

I am wondering if there is a way to wrap the steps or show them in such a way that does not cause the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

`p-steps` component does not work well in small screen resolutions if you are using more than 4 steps.
For my project I used a vertical stepper from [Angular Material Component](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview)
[image]